# How to redirect only websocket request to another server from apache windows?

Tags: windows, apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache2.4 config, which works well with `HTTPS` request.

Now, I'm trying to redirect `wss`(WebSocket) request to another server, where it running(On same server but on port `8000`).

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin YYYY.YYYY@XXXXX.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "D:/cert/certificate.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/cert/privatekey.key"

    # This is how I tried to redirect.
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Connection} Upgrade [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) wss://127.0.0.1:8000/$1  [P,L]
```

My WebSocket URL:

```
wss://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/home
```

The above config is not working. Please help!

Where I hit browser `https://127.0.0.1:8080/` Page is loading for a long time without any response on the screen.

**Edit-1:**

I solved by using `<Location 'path'>`. Can anyone help me to handle all WebSocket URLs?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by using the below code.

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>

    ServerAdmin YYYY.YYYY@XXXXX.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "D:/cert/certificate.cert"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/cert/privatekey.key"

    <Location "/ws/home">
       ProxyPass "wss://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/home"
    </Location>
```

But this won't work will all WebSocket URLs.